# Calling a JQuery function inside a condition

Tags: javascript, jquery, validation

I'm new to JS and JQuery and I'm trying implement the following functionality.

I have a form which has multiple inputs, each having its individual validation. These validations have been implemented inside one function.

```
function checkUpload() {
    var flagu1=0;
    var bookname = document.getElementById("title").value;

    var flagu2=0;
    .....
    .....
    var flagu6=0;

    if( flagu1==0 && flagu2==0 && flagu3==0 && flagu4==0 && flagu6==0 )
        return true;
    else 
        return false;
}
```

This validation function is executed when a user clicks on the following button:

```
<button class="btn btn-secondaryup" name="submit" value="Upload" id="submitmeup" data-loading-text="UPLOADING..." onclick="clearBox('uploaderror')" type="submit" style="width:100%">UPLOAD</button>
```

Now I'm trying to implement Bootstap's 'loading state button' in this. The functionality would work like this:

When a user clicks on the button, the front-end validation function is called. Once the validation function (checkUpload()) returns true, the following JQuery function should be called.

```
<script>
       $('#submitmeup').click(function() {
       var $btn = $(this);
       $btn.button('loading');
       setTimeout(function () {
       $btn.button('reset');
       }, 5000);
       });
</script>
```

The trick is that the button loading function has to be called only after the checkUpload function returns true. How do I implement this?

Comment: Is `checkUpload ` a synchronous method?

Comment: @LShetty Yes, it is. The function is called when the user clicks on the submit button

Answer (score 2, accepted):

use below code. Use function inside condition .if function returns true then it execute code in side if condition

```
 <script>
   $('#submitmeup').click(function() {
     var $btn = $(this);
     if(checkUpload()){
         $btn.button('loading');
         setTimeout(function () {
           $btn.button('reset');
         }, 5000);
       }
   });
</script>
```

Comment: Works like a charm. Thanks a lot man! Could you explain what you just did there? How is this checking for the checkUpload condition?

Comment: Your function return true or false base on your validations . so if it return true then code in side if function executed if false no code executed

Comment: This code works well. But for some reason, why validation error statements have been duplicated. After implementing this code, I'm getting two same statements for one error. Any idea why that could be happening after implementing this code?

Comment: Can you please add full code of function ?? This is only if condition it not fire two time until you click button two times

Comment: I just realised that the checkUpload function has already been called in the form above. So, now the function is being called twice. <form  class="upload" id="upload" onsubmit="return checkUpload();" action="" method="POST" enctype="multipart/form-data" >

Answer (score 0):

First remove the `onclick` attribute from the button:

```
<button class="btn btn-secondaryup" name="submit" value="Upload" id="submitmeup" data-loading-text="UPLOADING..." type="submit" style="width:100%">UPLOAD</button>
```

Then define your functions and set `.on('click')` event handler:

```
$(function() {

    var $submitButton = $('#submitmeup');

    // Submit handler
    function handleSubmit() {
        clearBox('uploaderror');

        var uploadValid = checkUpload();

        if (uploadValid) {
            // Upload successful
            showButtonLoading();
        }
    }

    function showButtonLoading() {
       $submitButton.button('loading');
       setTimeout(function () {
           $submitButton.button('reset');
       }, 5000);
    }

    function checkUpload() {
        var flagu1=0;
        var bookname = document.getElementById("title").value;

        var flagu2=0;
        .....
        .....
        var flagu6=0;

        if( flagu1==0 && flagu2==0 && flagu3==0 && flagu4==0 && flagu6==0 )
            return true;
        else 
            return false;
    }

    function clearBox(type) {
        // Your implementation here
    }

    // Event handler
    $submitButton.on('click', handleSubmit);

});
```

Now, clicking the button will go to `handleSubmit` function, which employs your code.